# How to replicate MongoDB's UNWIND feature dynamically across a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to normalize data in such a way that any values that are arrays result in 2 separate dictionary objects such that every expected key has a single associated value.

To take a sample use case that helps highlight the I/O I want, let us assume that I am trying to flatten a nested JSON object.

Now, in most examples I've seen I iterate through a nested dictionary and make a recursive call to a function that concatenates key names with any kind of delimiter if the value in a key value pair is a dict, using an index value in lieu of a key name if it's a list, and just passing the object through cleanly if it's neither type of iterable.

For example, the following sample dict:

```
[
    {
        "fruit": {
            "type": "apple",
            "color": "green"
        }
    },
    {
        "fruit": {
            "type": "pear",
            "color": "yellow"
        }
    },
    {
         "fruit": {
            "type": "grape",
            "color": ["red", "green"]
        }
    }
]
```

Might ideally return something closer to this:

```
[
    {
        "fruit.type": "apple",
        "fruit.color": "green"
    },
    {
        "fruit.type": "pear",
        "fruit.color": "green"
    },
    {
        "fruit.type": "grape",
        "fruit.color": "green"
    },
    {
        "fruit.type": "grape",
        "fruit.color": "red"
    }
]
```

Note that most use case would instead transform the "grape" dictionary into something more akin to this:

```
{
    "fruit.type": "grape",
    "fruit.color.1": "green",
    "fruit.color.2": "red"

}
```

Which is not desirable. An example of such code that I have used is as follows:

```
def flatten_json(dictionary):
out = {}

def flatten(object, name=""):

    if type(object) is dict:

        for key in object:
            flatten(object[key], name + key + ".")

    elif type(object) is list:

        i = 0
        for element in object:
            flatten(element, name + str(i) + ".")
            i += 1

    else:
        out[name[:-1]] = object

flatten(dictionary)
return out
```

For context, the underlying use-case is to ensure I am identifying completely unique instances of a behavior or record for more flexible presentation (such as in a datatable/csv), sorting, grouping, etc across multiple types of data sets. It's more desirable for me to have 4 records where every value is singular (i.e. no arrays/iterables).